# How to take a backup/Clone of object in c++

Tags: c++, object, backup

I have a class `SRecord` and object like this in C++

```
SRecord* CurrentCmnd;

CurrentCmnd = theStack->Pop(dig, operation1, resp_sol);
```

I would like to backup the `CurrentCmd` here

```
CurrentCmnd = theStack->Pop(dig, operation2, resp_sol);
```

After this operation I would like to use the `CurrentCmnd` which returns from the first `Pop` operation so that I can perform other checks on `CurrentCmnd`.

How can I take a back up of the above `CurrentCmnd` before Popping the second element from the stack.

Also want to mention that, I cannot inherit the SRecord Class, cannot use copy constructor.

I am looking for the solution something like below

```
 CurrentCmnd = theStack->Pop(dig, operation1, resp_sol);
```

Backup of CurrentCmnd.

```
SRecord* Temp_CurrentCmnd = CurrentCmnd;

CurrentCmnd = theStack->Pop(dig, operation2, resp_sol);

CurrentCmnd = Temp_CurrentCmnd;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some possible ways to achieve that, all methods assume the class has a copy constructor

**Simply using a copy constructor**

You could just use it to create a copy on-the-fly.

Creating a dynamically allocated copy (don't forget to free the memory once you are done with it):

```
SRecord * copy = new SRecord(*CurrentCmnd);
```

Creating a local copy (this copy will exists only throughout the scope of the method):

```
SRecord copy(*CurrentCmd);
```

**Adding a clone method to the object**

A clean way to implement this to is to add the following method to SRecord:

```
class SRecord {
     public:
         SRecord * createBackup() { return new Object(*this); }
}
```

Then you can just call:

```
SRecord * CurrentCmndBackup = CurrentCmnd->createBackup();
```

Don't forget to free the backup when you're done with it :)

**Generic implementation**

In my projects, I usually add this method to some base class from which I can inherit later. It looks like this:

```
class Cloneable {
     public:
         virtual Cloneable * clone() = 0;
}

class SRecord : public Cloneable {
     public:
         virtual Cloneable * clone() { return new SRecord(*this); }
}
```

**Smart Pointer implementation**

An even cleaner implementation uses smart pointers. In most of my projects I found these objects to be something I'd like to pass to other modules down the road, so I used shared pointers, but a unique pointer implementation is also legit.

Here is how it looks:

```
class Cloneable {
    public:
        using Sptr = std::shared_ptr<Cloneable>;
        virtual Sptr clone() = 0;
};

class SRecord : public Cloneable {
    public:
        using Sptr = std::shared_ptr<SRecord>;
        virtual Cloneable::Sptr clone() { return std::static_pointer_cast<Cloneable>(std::make_shared<SRecord>(*this)); }
};

int main()
{
    SRecord::Sptr a = std::make_shared<SRecord>();
    SRecord::Sptr b = std::static_pointer_cast<SRecord>(a->clone());
}
```

**Templated implementation**

As suggested, an additional implementation is using a templated clone method that is not part of any object:

```
template < typename T >
std::shared_ptr<T> clone(const T & obj) {
    return std::make_shared<T>(obj);
}
```

Comment: It would be safer to use a `std::unique_ptr` or a `std::shared_ptr` as the return value of `clone`.

Comment: @owacoder, I added a smart pointer implementation as well, since I agree that this is the right way to go :)

Comment: I don't get the advantage of inheritance here, C++ is not Java. A templated solution would be more natural in my opinion, and would factor code.

Comment: @YSC, Usually it's not some base class you use across your entire project, but rather a method you add to something like a BaseMessage class, if in your app messages need to be cloned so that each copy can be individually changed...

Comment: @YSC, Added a templated implementation as well, and it does seem nice!

Comment: Is there any other way instead of inheriting. Something like, taking a backup of the object into temp obj using assignment operator

Comment: @Sadhu, I added an even simpler implementation for you.